# Slicehost Alternatives

Tags: vps, virtualization, slicehost, private

What are some good alternatives to the virtual private server company sliceshost? I would like a few alternates providers.

Comment: This is newly useful now that slicehost is going away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Linode](http://www.linode.com/) are who I am with. They have very good pricing, good performance (google search "slicehost vs linode" for example) and a very active support community in the forums and IRC if you need help. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 2):

There are many, [SolarVPS](http://www.solarvps.com) is very good for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [OVH](http://www.ovh.co.uk/), they offer the RPS service which is essentially a diskless system connected to a large SAN. They also offer VPS style services as well.

Comment: I saw that service some days ago, as I have a dedicated at OVH, and sounds good... Have you tried that? For 10 euros a month the basic system seems better than a VPS, you know you aren't sharing nothng but the space... could be nice for a OpenSocial app or a new site...

Comment: You have a 100mbit connection that you share for net traffic and disk I/O to the SAN, so heavy I/O load reduces your net traffic and likewise reverse. It's a tradedown from a real dedicated machine but the flexibility allows OVH to reduce costs to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Webbynode -  cheaper but not better than Slicehost.

Answer (score 2):

VPSNet (vps dot net)

I use Slicehost, tough, but a colleague of mine uses VPSNet and likes it.

Answer (score 2):

I use vpsFarm for one of my personal images.  I chose it for the un-metered bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Network Redux has been awesome for me (and afforable)

networkredux dot com